# Midnight Commander: what does a * in front of file names mean?

Tags: midnight-commander

Midnight Commander: what does a '*' in front of file names mean?

Comment: And do you have a question to go along with that statement?

Comment: That sounds as if you somehow managed to make all files executable.

Comment: @mook765 I suggest you create an answer from your comment - that way we all get a useful post - thank you.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/432335/what-does-next-to-a-file-in-midnight-commander-mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [mc(1) manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc):

> type
>
> displays a one character wide type field. This character is similar to
>   what is displayed by ls with the -F flag - * for executable files, /
>   for directories, @ for links, = for sockets, - for character devices,
>   + for block devices, | for pipes, ~ for symbolic links to directories and ! for stale symlinks (links that point nowhere).

As stated in the manual, `*` signifies files with executable bit set

Comment: Does also refer to a 'tagged' file, from `man mc`: > mark   an asterisk if the file is tagged, a space if it's not.